# Rotate Icon on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a website with a navigation menu, there are also two dropdown menus, I have also placed 2 font awesome icons arrows on each of the dropdowns, but I am unsure how to make them rotate on when clicking the dropdown menus. I would like them to rotate 90 degrees down. I have already made the classes for the sub menus,

```js
let click = document.querySelector('.click');

let list = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-1');





click.addEventListener("click", () => {

  list.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-1');


});

let click2 = document.querySelector('.click2');

let list2 = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-2');



click2.addEventListener("click", () => {

  list2.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-2');


});
```

```css
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul li,
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-2 ul li {
  width: 110px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-Links" id="navLinks">
  <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>

  <ul>
    <li> <a href="Home.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="About.html">About Us</a> </li>
    <li class="click2">
      Recruiting <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

      <div class="Sub-menu-2">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="">Leave Request</a> </li>
    <li class="click"> CadetLinks <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

      <div id="navLinks1" class="Sub-menu-1">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Number 3</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use the css property `transform:rotate(90deg)` to rotate

Comment: Whenever you toggle the class you just have to use css property `transform: rotate(<degs>)`, for more info please read [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate())

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
list.onclick=function(){
    list.style.transform="rotate(90deg)";
}
list2.onclick=function(){
    list2.style.transform="rotate(90deg)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just used another icon but you can get the idea:

```js
let click = document.querySelector('.click');

let list = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-1');





click.addEventListener("click", () => {
    list.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-1');
    document.querySelector('.click .flaticon-hand-10').classList.toggle('gly');

});

let click2 = document.querySelector('.click2');

let list2 = document.querySelector('.Sub-menu-2');



click2.addEventListener("click", () => {

    list2.classList.toggle('NewSub-menu-2');
document.querySelector('.click2 .flaticon-hand-10').classList.toggle('gly');

});
```

```css
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul li,
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-2 ul li {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-left {
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Flaticon';
  src: url('data:font/ttf;base64,AAEAAAANAIAAAwBQRkZUTWzLl7IAAAV4AAAAHEdERUYAMQAGAAAFWAAAACBPUy8yL7pL5QAAAVgAAABWY21hcMARI74AAAHAAAABSmdhc3D//wADAAAFUAAAAAhnbHlmwP2S0wAAAxgAAABwaGVhZARhaP0AAADcAAAANmhoZWED0gHFAAABFAAAACRobXR4BgAAHgAAAbAAAAAQbG9jYQA4AAAAAAMMAAAACm1heHAARwAoAAABOAAAACBuYW1liNt9UwAAA4gAAAGScG9zdJJ3apwAAAUcAAAAMQABAAAAAQAAIRWaJV8PPPUACwIAAAAAANGhFEAAAAAA0aEUQAAe/8AB4gHAAAAACAACAAAAAAAAAAEAAAHA/8AALgIAAAAAAAHiAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAEAAAAEACUAAQAAAAAAAgAAAAEAAQAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAQIAAZAABQAIAUwBZgAAAEcBTAFmAAAA9QAZAIQAAAIABQkAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUGZFZABA4ADgAAHA/8AALgHAAEAAAAABAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAgAAHgAAAAMAAAADAAAAHAABAAAAAABEAAMAAQAAABwABAAoAAAABgAEAAEAAgAA4AD//wAAAADgAP//AAAgAwABAAAAAAAAAAABBgAAAQAAAAAAAAABAgAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAAAAAEAHv/AAeIBwAAkAAAlIgcuASMiBy4BIyIHNTQmIgYdAScuAQ4BHwEeATsBMjY9ATQmAa0ODQMdExANBRsRDgwfLB8SDyshAg5zEjYYcS9CH9sHEhgIDxMIexYfHxbtFRADHSwQgRIaOyqBFh8AAAAAAAwAlgABAAAAAAABAAgAEgABAAAAAAACAAcAKwABAAAAAAADACQAfQABAAAAAAAEAAgAtAABAAAAAAAFAAsA1QABAAAAAAAGAAgA8wADAAEECQABABAAAAADAAEECQACAA4AGwADAAEECQADAEgAMwADAAEECQAEABAAogADAAEECQAFABYAvQADAAEECQAGABAA4QBmAGwAYQB0AGkAYwBvAG4AAGZsYXRpY29uAABSAGUAZwB1AGwAYQByAABSZWd1bGFyAABGAG8AbgB0AEYAbwByAGcAZQAgADIALgAwACAAOgAgAGYAbABhAHQAaQBjAG8AbgAgADoAIAAxADMALQA2AC0AMgAwADEANQAARm9udEZvcmdlIDIuMCA6IGZsYXRpY29uIDogMTMtNi0yMDE1AABmAGwAYQB0AGkAYwBvAG4AAGZsYXRpY29uAABWAGUAcgBzAGkAbwBuACAAMQAuADAAAFZlcnNpb24gMS4wAABmAGwAYQB0AGkAYwBvAG4AAGZsYXRpY29uAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAEAAgECBmhhbmQxMAAAAAAAAAH//wACAAEAAAAOAAAAGAAAAAAAAgABAAMAAwABAAQAAAACAAAAAAABAAAAAMmJbzEAAAAA0aEUQAAAAADRoRRA') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.flaticon-hand-10:before {
  content: "\e000";
}

li > i {
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.gly {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
 <li class="click2">
                    Recruiting  
<i class="flaticon-hand-10"></i>
                    <div class="Sub-menu-2">

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Leave Request</a> </li>
                <li  class="click"> CadetLinks 
                <i class="flaticon-hand-10"></i>

                    <div id="navLinks1" class="Sub-menu-1">

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Number 3</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to add a transition

Answer (score -1):

Try this. The transform is done on hover but you can use different events.

```css
    .nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-1 ul li,
.nav-Links ul li .Sub-menu-2 ul li {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-left {
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.link-icon{
   
    transition:2s;
}
.link-icon:hover{
       -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<ul>

                <li> <a href="Home.html">Home</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="About.html">About Us</a> </li>
                <li class="click2">
                    Recruiting  <span class="link-icon fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

                    <div class="Sub-menu-2">

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="">Leave Request</a> </li>
                <li  class="click"> CadetLinks  <span class="fas fa-chevron-left"></span>

                    <div id="navLinks1" class="Sub-menu-1">

                        <ul>

                            <li><a href="#">Number 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Number 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Number 3</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's onclick not onhover

Comment: For onclick simple switch the class instead.

Comment: Sorry Mohit wdym you mean change class to 'click', i dont have an option for click